# How to ignore some resources/urls for everyone in spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-rest

I have some urls (one as of now) which I would like to allow for every users like registration and login urls. I only want to exclude any url path after register and secure or restrict any other urls.

Please refer the code below:

```
   package com.travelplanner.rest.config;

    //COPY
    import javax.sql.DataSource;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.UserBuilder;
    import org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager;
    import org.springframework.security.provisioning.UserDetailsManager;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        private DataSource securityDataSource;

        @Bean
        public UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager() {
            JdbcUserDetailsManager jdbcUserDetailsManager = new JdbcUserDetailsManager();
            jdbcUserDetailsManager.setDataSource(securityDataSource);
            return jdbcUserDetailsManager;
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(securityDataSource);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.cors().and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable()     
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/register/**").permitAll();
        }

    }
```

It is a spring mvc rest in google app engine. I have used the above snippet and it says unauthorised even for the antmatchers. Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JaiDixit I have updated the code above. I only want the /register/** to be ignored and rest to be secured.I have tried ("/register/**") and it did not work.

Comment: Request is localhost8080/api/register/user

Comment: so your ant matcher should be configured as .antMatchers("/api/register/**")

Answer (score -1):

It's probably the `httpBasic()` part which is requiring authentication. You should put specific instructions first and more general ones at last, so try with this:

```
http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("api/users/register/user").permitAll()
    .and()
    .anyRequest().httpBasic();
```

This allows everyone to access "api/users/register/user", but requires http authentication for other URLs.